# String formatting help

Tags: php, html, string, datetime

I have this: `2010-04-08T01:01:00Z`

I want to remove the 'T' and everything behind it as well.

Also I would like to rewrite the date into this format: `08-04-2010`

How can I do this the easiest way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
date("d-m-Y",strtotime("2010-04-08T01:01:00Z"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `strftime` is what you are looking for.

For example, `strftime('%c')` gives you something like 'Thur Apr 21, 2011 8:00am' -- you just need to find the format you want.  Of course, having said that, I was assuming that your timestamp is not just a string.  If it is, this might not help you at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple

```
substr($t, 0, 10);
```

? The date part is always 10 characters long (even ASCII), as long as it's an ISO date.

Reversing order is a bit trickier, but doable, too:

```
$new = join("-", array_reverse(explode("-", substr($t, 0, 10))));
```

There's nothing wrong with the other, `date` based answers, but this would work, too.